# How to set my custom values on Y-axis of my chart

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [teechart problem for series label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011648/teechart-problem-for-series-label)

Is There any way to print labels ex.  Jan , Feb , Mar....  On Y-axis of tchart

In

Borland c++

Comment: I already answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011648/teechart-problem-for-series-label/7344527#7344527). If that's not the same problem please provide more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Borland C++, but assuming the TeeChart that comes with it is the same as the ActiveX TeeChart, you'll need to do something like this:

```
chart.Axis.Left.Labels.Clear(); // Clear current labels
chart.Axis.Left.Labels.Add(1, "January"); // Repeat for other months
```