# how to set my own values on Y axis of teechart in borland c++

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set my custom values on Y-axis of my chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969719/how-to-set-my-custom-values-on-y-axis-of-my-chart)

I am having great trouble to set labels of Y axis with my own values.
like  1= Jan ,2= Feb ,3 = Mar .....

I show same thread but solution was not working.

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

I have created series and displayed them on chart.
I have not written any code to show my strings on Y-Axis instead of default integer values.

I am not getting axes named property in Chart(TChart) object.

Comment: and you have posted the same question previously: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6969719/811335

Comment: I already answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011648/teechart-problem-for-series-label/7344527#7344527). If that's not the same problem please provide more detailed information.