# teechart problem for series label

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

```
series[0]->AddXY(30,10,'label1',clRed);
series[0]->parent = chart;
```

This is my code to print 1 series on chart.
Now I am getting label1  printed on X axis.
Is there any way to print this label on Yaxis.

Answer (score 0):

You should set left axis *LabelStyle* to *talText*, for example:

```
Chart1->Axes->Left->LabelStyle = talText;
```